# "Could not find a declaration file for module", custom declaration file in typeRoots folder is ignored

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsconfig, tsc

Hi I am stuck with a TypeScript problem. I have the following directory structure:

- package.json: the top project
- node_modules/: all installed libraries
- tsconfig.json
- build/: a generated folder

  - index.js
  - handler.js
  - ...
- server/: a folder with a TypeScript server built on top of the build folder

  - typings/

    - handler/

      - index.d.ts
  - tsconfig.json:
  - index.ts: a TypeScript server

The file server/tsconfig.json contains the lines

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types",
            "./typings"
        ],
    ...
    "include": [
        "./*.ts",
        "./typings/**/*.ts"
    ],
```

I import an un-typed JavaScript function in TypeScript in the file server/index.ts:

```
import { handler } from '../build/handler.js'
... (code using handler) ...
```

The file server/typings/handler/index.d.ts contains

```
declare module 'handler' {
    export const handler: (a: any) => void 
}
```

But this declaration file is not picked up by `tsc`. Running `npx tsc  --project server/tsconfig.json"` gives

```
server/index.ts(6,25): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '../build/handler.js'. '/home/..../build/handler.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Adding `--traceResolution` shows that the build/handler.d.ts file location is checked, but the typings/handler/index.d.ts location is not checked.

I have read [Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam) but this does not mention a relative import.

I tried [Could not find declaration file with custom declaration file for 'react-dates' module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159691/could-not-find-declaration-file-with-custom-declaration-file-for-react-dates-m) but it doesn't help.

How can I make TypeScript detect the handler.d.ts file in the typeRoots directory?